# Store specific lines from a multiline file as values in a dictionary (Python)

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex, dictionary

I have a multiline transcript file that contains lines of text and corresponding timestamps. It looks like this:

```
00:02:01,640  00:02:04,409
word word CHERRY word word

00:02:04,409  00:02:07,229
word APPLE word word

00:02:07,229  00:02:09,380
word word word word

00:02:09,380  00:02:12,060
word BANANA word word word
```

Now, if the text contains specific words (types of fruit) which I have already stored in a list, these words shall be stored as keys in a dictionary. My code for this:

```
Dict = {}
FruitList = []

for w in transcript.split():
    if w in my_list:
        FruitList.append(w)
      
keys = FruitList
```

The output of printing `keys` is: `['CHERRY', 'APPLE', 'BANANA']`.

Moving on, my problem is that I want to extract the timestamps belonging to the lines containing fruits, and store them in the dictionary as values - but only those timestamps which correspond to the line underneath in which a type of fruit is given.
For this task, I have several code snippets:

```
values = [] # shall contain timestamps later

timestamp_pattern = re.compile(r"\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2},\d{3}  \d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2},\d{3}")


for i in keys:
    Dict[i] = values[i]
```

Unfortunately, I have no idea how to write the code in order to get only the relevant timestamps and store them as values with their keys (fruits) in the Dict.

The desired output (Dict) should look like this:

```
{'CHERRY': '00:02:01,640 -> 00:02:04,409', 

'APPLE': '00:02:04,409 -> 00:02:07,229', 

'BANANA': '00:02:09,380 -> 00:02:12,060'}
```

Can anyone help?

Thank you very much!

Comment: Check https://ideone.com/QAzbwj

Comment: Have you had time to check my approach? Does it work for you? If not, what is the problem?

Comment: @WiktorStribizew: I'm sorry for the late answer but something came in between so I didn't have enough time yesterday evening to test it. I will try your approach now and let you know if it works for me :-)

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew: Yes, it works! Thank you! However, this approach is unfortunately not 100 percent ideal for my task because the types of fruit need to be typed in manually in the regex pattern. But as for my transcripts, it is not sure which fruits will appear in the text or if there will be any at all. If there are, they should be handled exactly like in the output of your approach. :-)

Comment: It is not a problem, just build the pattern dynamically, see my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like something you can do using `zip` and avoid regex, considering the pattern of lines:

```
d = {}
lines = transcript.split('\n')
for x, y in zip(lines, lines[1:]):
    for w in my_list:
        if w in y.split():
            splits = x.split()
            d[w] = f'{splits[0]} -> {splits[1]}'
            
print(d)
```

Comment: Hm, unfortunately I get back an empty dict with this approach, and I'm trying to find out why.

Comment: @mareikesthesis, I assumed `transcript` is a list of lines. Were you checking the same way?

Comment: `transcript` is a string and `my_list` is a list. Sorry, I should have mentioned this earlier, I guess.

Comment: No worries. Updated accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

You may use

```
^(\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2},\d{3}  \d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2},\d{3})\n.*\b(CHERRY|APPLE|BANANA)\b
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/VYxcZA/1). With this pattern, you capture the time span line and the keyword into separate groups that can be retrieved with `re.findall`. After swapping the two captured values, you may cast the list of tuples into a dictionary.

If you read the data from a file, you need to use `with open(fpath, 'r') as r:` and then `contents = r.read()` to read the whole contents into a single string variable.

See [Python demo](https://ideone.com/fiVnZY):

```
import re
text = "00:02:01,640  00:02:04,409\nword word CHERRY word word\n\n00:02:04,409  00:02:07,229\nword APPLE word word\n\n00:02:07,229  00:02:09,380\nword word word word\n\n00:02:09,380  00:02:12,060\nword BANANA word word word"
t = r"\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2},\d{3}"
keys = ['CHERRY', 'APPLE', 'BANANA']
rx = re.compile(fr"^({t}  {t})\n.*\b({'|'.join(keys)})\b", re.M)
print( dict([(y,x) for x, y in rx.findall(text)]) )
```

Output:

```
{'CHERRY': '00:02:01,640  00:02:04,409', 'APPLE': '00:02:04,409  00:02:07,229', 'BANANA': '00:02:09,380  00:02:12,060'}
```